# DataStage - issue with an input sequential file with pipe delimited

Tags: transform, extract, etl, datastage

Source: Text file in UNIX box

DS Stage: Sequential file

Sample record (Line 1):

```
Div03|Fac-12|Labor|2,543.30
```

Short desc:

- Stage is Pipe delimited and all are `VarChar`
- connected to a transformer to convert it to `Decimal(19,2)`
- output is a table in Oracle, but couldn't read the last record `(2,543.30)`
- last record `(2,543.30)`, display as `0`

HELP:

I need to display the last record as is and doesn't have comma but still have decimal. How?

Comment: Remove the comma in the transformer before you convert it to a decimal - have you tried that?

Comment: Are you positive its reading the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Cause , (comma) is treated as string in datastage, remove it first and then try to read it